# Not able to enable pdo_mysql extension or not able to install

Tags: mysql, php, magento

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS , Using PHP version 5.6 i have required 5.6 version only not required php latest version

I tried to install or tried to enable but not working:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-mysql

E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

I am getting below error.

```
pdo_mysql extension is not installed
```

Comment: Which is it `php5-mysql` or `pdo_mysql`?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install php-pdo-mysql`

Comment: Can you provide more explanation about what is `php-pdo-mysql`package? for example, what contains that package, ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, i have resolved issue.

I have executed below commands in terminal.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As of version 16.04, Ubuntu comes with php7 by default. You need to install php5 repository. This might help:

```
#sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Comment: Already installed and done downgrade 
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: did you do apt update?

Comment: Hi Vichu, Not working tried
change the cd /etc/php/5.6/apache2
nano php.ini but not working

Comment: what is the output of php -m?

Comment: Alex, Here is output
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

Comment: have you tried apt-get install pdo-mysql?

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

in your php.ini

restart the webserver (e.g. with "sudo service apache2 restart")